# How change format in C# using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm developing a function that allows me to generate a file PDF format but the problem I have is in the format issue: for example, what I want is to generate this part of text:

> "Hi, I'm a **programming student** and I need help to solve this problem" //expected

However, at the output of the file I get the same text without taking into account the part in bold.

> "Hi, I'm a programming student and I need help to solve this problem" //generated

my code:

```
string directory = @"c:\";      
FileStream fs = new FileStream(directoriopdf, FileMode.Create);
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

Font standarFont2 = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

         var text = new Paragraph("Hi, I'm a programming student and I need help to solve this problem", standarFont2);
         text.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
         doc.Add(text);
         doc.Close();
         pw.Close();
```

on the other hand, do you know how to align two texts on the same line using itextsharp?, for example expected is this  [image]

code:

```
Font standarFont3 = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
var row1 = new Paragraph("Jersfyah\nStudent", standarFont3);
var row2 = new Paragraph("Carl\nUniversity professor", standarFont3);
row1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
row2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
doc.Add(row1);
doc.Add(row2);
```

Comment: I already managed to solve the format issue:  using **chunk** but I can't align two sentences on the same line

Comment: As you essentially have a table there, two rows and two columns, I would propose using an iText table (`PdfPTable`). Alternatively you can try with TAB chunks.